# Configuring Log4j2 for multiple packages

Tags: log4j2

This is my properties file.I have defined 2 packages here.I want logger across my whole application.What if i have 10-12 packages in my application.Is this the only approach??

```
name=PropertiesConfig
property.filename =/myfolder
appenders = console, file

appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = %d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss} [%-5p] [%c] [%M] %x - %m%n
appender.file.type = File
appender.file.name = LOGFILE
appender.file.fileName=${filename}/logs.txt
appender.file.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.file.layout.pattern=%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss} [%-5p] [%c] [%M] %x - %m%n

loggers=file,myfile
logger.file.name=servlets
logger.file.level = debug,info
logger.file.appenderRefs = file
logger.file.appenderRef.file.ref = LOGFILE


logger.myfile.name=com.util
logger.myfile.level = debug,info
logger.myfile.appenderRefs = file
logger.myfile.appenderRef.myfile.ref = LOGFILE

rootLogger.level =com.debug
rootLogger.appenderRefs = stdout
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
```

Answer (score 2):

First, your configuration doesn't look valid to me. You have

```
logger.myfile.name=com.util
logger.myfile.level = debug,info
logger.myfile.appenderRefs = file
logger.myfile.appenderRef.myfile.ref = LOGFILE

rootLogger.level =com.debug
rootLogger.appenderRefs = stdout
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
```

You cannot specify 2 levels on logger.myfile.level. Specifying debug will include all debug, info, warn, error and fatal events.

Secondly, you have rootLogger.level =com.debug. I would assume this should be `rootLogger.level=debug`?

To answer your question, yes you have to configure a logger for each pattern you want to match. However the Logger declaration can delegate some of its configuration to its parent. The only thing that is generally required is the level attribute.

So you could specify:

```
logger.a.name=com.util.marketing.sub1
logger.a.level=debug
logger.b.name=com.util.marketing.sub2
logger.b.level=error
logger.c.name=com.util.marketing
logger.c.level=info
logger.c.appenderRefs=file
logger.c.appenderRef.file=LOGFILE
```

Personally, I prefer XML as I find it more concise and clearer. The above would be

```
<Logger name="com.util.marketing.sub1" level="DEBUG"/>
<Logger name="com.util.marketing.sub2" level="ERROR"/>
<Logger name="com.util.marketing" level="INFO">
  <AppenderRef ref="LOGFILE"/>
</Logger>
```